# Search for a particular spoken word in audio files

Tags: speech-recognition

I have around 3000+ audio files of the same author. I need to transcribe those lectures, where the author has said about a particular word.

So I need a software solution, which will find automatically all the files where the particular word is said.  There can be some variation how the word has been spoken , because the audio files were spoken over 15 years.

Free/Open Source solution is appreciated.

I tried searching , and got to know about Sphinx. But I am unable to set it up to use for my project. Any help is greatly appreciated. Please

Comment: hey were you able to achieve this? if so please share how? github repo would be great!

Comment: I'm with DJ_Stuffy_K. I'm interested in your solution also.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net), an open source speech recognition engine which has support for keyword spotting.

1) convert the audio to required format - 16khz 16bit mono files:

```
 ffmpeg -i file.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 file.wav
```

2) build and install latest pocketsphinx and sphinxbase from http://github.com/cmusphinx

3) Download [en-us generic acoustic model](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Acoustic%20Model/en-us.tar.gz/download)

4) run the detection:

```
  pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav -hmm en-us -kws_threshold 1e-40 -keyphrase "what you need to detect" -time yes
```

It will print you detected keywords and their times. For the best detection accuracy you can adjust kws_threshold.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay for your answer. Since this accoustic model will be generic, how can I make a accoustic model based upon the speaker's already recorded audio files?

Comment: For keyword spotting you do NOT need speaker-dependent model, it will not improve things significantly. In case you still want to adapt it there is an acoustic model adaptation tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

Comment: Will the keyword spotting still work , if the keyword I am searching for is not in the standard English dictionary?

Comment: Also there is one problem, that the speaker cannot speak normally like before due to paralysis, and therefore speaker cannot speak the training texts for the accoustic model. Is there any way , by which the model can be trained by using the already transcribed audio files? Thank You

Comment: If keyword is missing in the standard dictionary you need to create a dictionary with that keyword. You can specify and fine-tune the pronuciation there. You can load it with -dic <your.dic> in the command line.

Comment: Yes, you can use already transcribed audio files for model adaptation. The model adaptation is not different, instead of recording new audio you are using existing ones. You just need to cut it on sentences.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answers. Is there any tutorial available for how to add our own missing keyword in the dictionary??

Comment: Hi, Can Acoustic Fingerprinting method be used for this task??Please reply

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev . I am working on similar task. I have a bunch of recorded audio conversations. I want to uniquely identify non speech portions of the call. for example where do "ringtones-dialtones-waitmusic" etc. occur in a call
Please advise how to achieve this. thank you Sir.